# GraphQL "batchOperations" with @export directive

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

A couple of years ago I created [this github issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/462) with the slide below from a [GraphQL talk at React Europe by Lee Byron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViXL0YQnioU). The slide depicts "batchOperations" using what's called a `@export` directive. This at the time was an experimental part of the GraphQL api, and still is not a widely supported standard feature.

My question is now that some time has passed. Is this possible? Specifically is it possible using Apollo? I checked for native support for this directive with Apollo server, and the playground is giving me the error `Unknown directive @export`.

I found a reference to the directive here in the docs:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#export-directive

However it seems to be bundled with a `@rest` directive.

I also found a reference to directives in the config for Apollo Client:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/devtools/apollo-config/#clientclientonlydirectives-clientclientschemadirectives

[image: Slide from Lee Byron's talk on GraphQL displaying API for @export directive]

(This is simply a slide from a talk, not a working code example )

It would be nice to see a working example of this functionality in an example repo if it is possible, even if it doesn't take the same shape (api design) as the slide above. If it is possible it seems that there is a certain amount of configuration from setting up Apollo Server, and Apollo Client, as well as the playground.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the `@export` directive is still not supported.

And I doubt it will be worked on anytime soon, considering that GraphQL's existing features were already designed specifically to support this kind of operation batching.

Here's how your example would look like with the good old GraphQL pattern:

```
query {
  feed {
    stories {
      id
      actor
      message
      comments {
        actor
        messages
      }
    }
  }
}
```

IMHO the classic pattern looks way cleaner than having 2 separate queries who's result you'll probably have to manually merge on the frontend side.

If you absolutely can not add those sub fields to your schema then you can consider creating REST endpoints that perform multiple GraphQL operations in sequence.
But that really goes against GraphQL's principles.

As a side note: it probably wouldn't be hard to add a custom `@export` directive and add support for this new kind of batched operations if you're familiar enough with GraphQL, but I don't believe there is much interest in this.